# find: missing argument to `-exec' in SSH command

Tags: ssh, find, chmod

I'm using SSH inside a CI/CD Pipeline (so it's non-interactive), and trying to execute a couple `find` command (among others) to change the ownership of files and directories after executing LFTP *mirror*, but I keep getting this error (which makes the whole Pipeline fail):

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

This is the command that uses `find`:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $USERNAME@$HOST "[other commands...]; find $SOME_PATH/ -type d -exec 'chmod 755 {} \;' && find $SOME_PATH/ -type f -exec 'chmod 644 {} \;' && echo Done"
```

I've already tried using escaped double quotes like so: `-exec \"chmod 755 {} \;\"` - but keeps throwing the same error.

What would be the main issue here?

---

**EDIT: Solved.** I removed any quotes for the `-exec`, removed the `&&` and append an extra semicolon `;` to each `find` and it works as expected.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $USERNAME@$HOST "[other commands...]; find $SOME_PATH/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;; find $SOME_PATH/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;; echo Done"
```

So use `-exec whatever-command {} \;; [other command, echo, find, ls, whatever...]`.

Please check this answer for more information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139800/291364

> [...] When `find` sees that spurious `exit` after the `-exec … ;` directive, it doesn't know what to do with it; it hazards a (wrong) guess that you meant it to be a path to traverse. You need a command separator: put another `;` after `\;` (with or without a space before). [...]

Answer (score 1):

`\;` is processed to `;` *locally* before the string is passed to the remote shell. You need to escape the backslash so the the `;` remains escaped on the remote end.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $USERNAME@$HOST  \
    "[other commands...]; find $SOME_PATH/ -type d -exec 'chmod 755 {} \\;'
       && find $SOME_PATH/ -type f -exec 'chmod 644 {} \\;' && echo Done"
```

A better idea would be to use single quotes for the command argument and pass the value of `$SOME_PATH` as an argument to a shell.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $USERNAME@$HOST \
  sh -c '...;
         find "$1" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; &&
         find "$1" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&
         echo Done' _ "$SOME_PATH"
```

Note that `chmod` and its arguments each need to be separate arguments to the `find`.

In fact, you don't need to run `find` twice; you can provide two `-exec` primaries, each paired to a different `-type`:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $USERNAME@$HOST \
  sh -c '...;
         find "$1" \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; \) -o
                   \( -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; \)
         && echo Done' _ "$SOME_PATH"
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't know that I can pass arguments like that and reuse `find` I fixed it using `{} \;;` tho, that'll work for now, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the complex `find` commands (and associated quoting/escaping mess), you can use the built-in capabilities of `chmod` sympolic modes to set the permissions on files and directores differently. Specifically, the "`X`" permission means essentially "execute if it makes sense", which mostly means directories rather than files. The main exception is that if there's a file that already has execute set, it assumes it's intentional and keeps it. If that's ok, you can use this simpler command:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX "$1"    # Set non-executable files to 644, executables and directories to 755
```

If you need to specifically clear execute bits on files, or just want to stick with `find`, another option take advantage of the fact that `chmod` accepts multiple arguments to use `find ... -exec ... {} +` instead of the `\;` version. "`+`" isn't a shell metacharacter, so it doesn't reqire special treatment:

```
find $SOME_PATH/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + ; find $SOME_PATH/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```